# How to set hero build in Arcade game in Dota2?

Tags: dota-2

Whenever I create a hero build, I only able to see it under the "Learn" game, but not "Arcade" game. The same goes for other published hero build. Everything does not show up in "Arcade" game, only the standard Valve hero build. Any way to solve this?

I've tried the following:

- Login to the hero build webpage from the Steam in-game web browser
- Verify integrity of game cache
- Reinstalling dota2

But all do not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think in arcade mode, because the games may have different items (custom items) they might have disabled he guides/builds in arcade mode. You can make sure that you saved your build, because that may be the problem you are having. I hope this helped a tiny bit.
You can also check this link out for more information on how to get the guide, if that is the problem you are having. The link is [How to enable the dota2 ingame guides](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129591/how-to-enable-the-dota2-ingame-guides?rq=1)